# Find out if statUpdatingLocation is active in Swift

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I have a location based app running in swift. I am trying to detect if the `self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` is currently active.

I am struggling to find out how to do this nor can I find much on the internet about it. This I am fairly sure is rather simple to achieve. I don't want to set a BOOL as this needs to be global.

```
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() && /* START UPDATE LOCATION GOES HERE */ {

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        sender.setTitle("END DAY", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    } else {


    }
```

Comment: Are you interested in startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges or startUpdatingLocation?

Comment: It shouldn't really matter if its significant or general updating as they share the same delegate surely.

Comment: "shouldn't really matter if its significant or general updating as they share the same delegate surely" Life is not about "shouldn't" and "surely" when you are programming a framework. It's about "is". No use wishing things were different; you have to think about how things are. Of course it makes a difference. They are completely different kinds of updating; they operate independently.

Comment: p.s. wasn't wishing, just expecting ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is a late answer now.  But this is possibly one solution if you want to know if the locationManager is updating.

There should only be one instance of `CLLocationManager` in your app. So creating a Singleton is ideal. Then, you should override the methods `startUpdatingLocation` and `stopUpdatingLocation`.

**(Swift 3)**

```
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: CLLocationManager {
    var isUpdatingLocation = false

    static let shared = LocationManager()

    override func startUpdatingLocation() {
        super.startUpdatingLocation()

        isUpdatingLocation = true
    }

    override func stopUpdatingLocation() {
        super.stopUpdatingLocation()

        isUpdatingLocation = false
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
  if LocationManager.shared.isUpdatingLocation {
    print("Is currently updating location.")
  } else {
    print("Location updates have stopped.")
  }
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing but will be handy for anyone who stumbles across this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *not* know whether `startUpdatingLocation()` is "active" because *you are the one who said it*.

If you need to keep track of this from elsewhere, make a Bool property and set it to `true` when you call `startUpdatingLocation()` and to `false` when you call `stopUpdatingLocation()`.

Comment: Actual example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift (the property in my code is called `trying`).

Comment: I don't fully understand you first paragraph comment tbh. Surely there must be a way of checking without a BOOL if the location tracking is active? As statedf above,  I ideally don't want a BOOL as this is a background operation throughout the whole app. Is there not a property I can check against `startUpdatingLocation` for example `if locationManager.isUpdating {` ....

Comment: You are just making me repeat myself. No, there is no `locationManager.isUpdating`. If there were, you would know about it. There doesn't _need_ to be one, because it isn't updating unless you _told_ it to start updating.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll need to set this in NSDefault for my purposes. Thanks for the clarification Matt

Comment: @matt this type of answer is completely useless. You are apparently not aware that there are people working on apps with hundreds or thousands of other engineers with very complicated logic -- it might not be "you" who started the location manager updating and it might not be feasible to track down.

Comment: @BrennanVincent That may be true, but that won't make `locationManager.isUpdating` spring into existence. I didn't say that this situation is _good_; I'm just presenting it as I imagine Apple must see it, since it's their API that is missing something people clearly need. Don't shoot the messenger!

Comment: @matt fair enough, but that also doesn't make the any usefulness to the answer spring into existence either.

Comment: @BrennanVincent fair enough! I will defend to the death your right to downvote me.